# how to keep app running when screen off or open another app?

Tags: android

How to keep app running when screen off or open another app,just like some running track app . when user running they can also track user's pace.
I don't know how to start with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` permission.

First add this permission in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

In your activity :

```
import android.os.PowerManager;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    protected PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        /* This code together with the one in onDestroy() 
         * will make the screen be always on until this Activity gets destroyed. */
        final PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        this.mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
        this.mWakeLock.acquire();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.mWakeLock.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Or you can add this code before setContentView activity. like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle icicle) {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```